# C# SMTPClient - send attachment to the e-mail

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm using the code below within a script task in `SSIS` in order to send an e-mail. What I also want, is to send an attachment to the e-mail which is a file on the local computer and the name of the file is formed by name of the file and `GETDATE()` function and is stored in a variable. How can I adapt my code in order to use the file from that variable as the attachment?

```
  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("myemail@gmail.com", "t@mail.ro", "Teee", "WWWWW");
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    client.EnableSsl=true;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "password");

    System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
    contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
    contentType.Name = "ERPOrder(s)_20180810050711.csv";
    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("‪C:\\FMLogistics\\ERPOrder(s)_20180810050711.csv", contentType));

    client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, if I have understood your question properly,

```
string FileName = "ERPOrder(s)_20180810050711.csv";
string FilePath = Path.Combine("‪C:\\FMLogistics", FileName);

contentType.Name = FileName;
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FilePath, contentType));
```

Comment: This would have worked if the name of the file would've been static, which will not. `ERPOrder(s)_` is static but what comes after underscore (_), will always be different due to the output of `GETDATE()` function. So, if I generate the file tomorrow the name of the file would be different.

Comment: @srkkk OK, can you generate the date in .NET instead of in SQ? in .NET you can also get a date/time string like that and as it runs on the same server it will have same value as the GETDATE

Comment: I'm generating this file through a software developed in .NET, to a specific location. What I want next, is to take whatever the file is there with .csv extension and send it through e-mail.